# Running PHP on the Command Line Throws Module Errors About SNMP

Tags: php

When I run any command using PHP on the command line I get a bunch of errors about modules:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ php -v

MIB search path: /home/vagrant/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 34 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 37 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdavis ::= { enterprises 2021 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 39 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: ucdDlmodMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 14 }
Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 13 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (MTA-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 15 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: ucdDiskIOMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 15 }
Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 19 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 15 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmSensors ::= { ucdExperimental 16 }
Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 32 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
```

This is just a sample. Why can't the modules be found? I am assuming that is the course of all the messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove php5-snmp package. You can use this command in a console to do so:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-snmp
```

- from google search : `php UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt`
- first result : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257589/ubuntu-typing-php-in-terminal-shows-a-lot-of-errors